# pandas to_sql() wrongly increments most significant digit(MSD) of the index

Tags: python, sql, pandas

I have a Postgres table, with index ending at id 754238.
But when insert a new data frame using pandas to_sql() command below.
it increments the LSD, but also increments MSD **8**5423**9**

> df_transformed.to_sql(domain, db_local, schema='public',if_exists='append',index=False)

Indeed, I was expecting only **754239**
May I know what causes this, and how to rectify this issue.

Comment: is the new dataframe unique? there are no repeat data from the dataframe that was already exising in the table?

Comment: there are no duplicates of the primary key, as a matter of fact, this "index" is the primary key, ie. ID in the Postgres table.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue, by manually aligning the index, but not sure why Pandas does this weird thing. 
Even in the latest version of pandas '1.0.3', I see this behaviour.

```
sql_get_max_id = f'select max({index_name}) as id from {table}'
max_id = pd.read_sql(sql_get_max_id, db_local_otp)[index_name][0]
new_id_base = max_id + 1
df.index += new_id_base
df.index.name = index_name
df.to_sql(table, db_local_otp, if_exists='append')
```